# Top 10 Firstnames - Multiple tables (Union) - SQL

Tags: sql, union, limit

I would like to have the top 10 of the most present firstnames in Database with several tables

For 1 table:

```
SELECT n.prenomsNouveauNe, COUNT(*)
FROM <database>.naissance n
GROUP BY n.prenomsNouveauNe
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

For multiple tables:

```
(
 SELECT
  n.prenomNouveauNe, COUNT(*)
  FROM
   <database>.naissance n
   group by n.prenomsNouveauNe
)
UNION ALL
(
 SELECT
  d.prenomDefunt, count(*)
  FROM
   <database>.deces d
   group by d.prenomDefunt
)
```

But I can not get the top 10 ...

Comment: Which DB you are using , also can you share some sample data via sql fiddle?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, it's MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select theName, count(*) as cnt from
(
 SELECT
  n.prenomNouveauNe as theName
  FROM
   genearmor.naissance n
UNION ALL
 SELECT
  d.prenomDefunt as theName
  FROM
   <database>.deces d
) tmp
group by theName
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```